# How to download a sharepoint aspx page from server using powershell

Tags: powershell, aspx, tfs, download

I made some changes to sp aspx pages on a environment. I want to move these changes to my TFS. Usually one takes the pages using designer, save it to the desktop, and save that to TFS.

But is there a powershell way of automating this? - meaning just saving the desired aspx pages to the filesystem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for. You can export a specific file or object from the Export-SPWeb context, not the whole kitten kaboodle.

```
Export-SPWeb -identity "http://sharepoint" -ItemUrl "/default.aspx"  -Path "c:\default.aspx" 

Import-SPWeb -identity "http://sharepoint" -Path "C:\default.aspx"
```

Comment: Hi. But where do we specify the relative folder it might be in...for e.g. what if I am trying to download/upload `http://localhost:5566/Section1/SubSec1/somepage.aspx`?

Comment: then your `-ItemUrl` will be `section1/subsection1/somepage.aspx`

Comment: when you import it, only the item specified in the export will be imported...

Answer (score 5):

As I understood you need source of the file from content DB to check it into Source Control. Please, try the following code:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb <path to web>
$file = $web.GetFile('<relative path to file>');
$bytes = $file.OpenBinary();
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes('<path to file on your disk>', $bytes);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use WebRequest

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $webUrl
$path = "C:\file.aspx"

$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$request.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

#do web request - if exception -> item does not exist
try {
    $response = [System.Net.WebResponse]$request.GetResponse();
    if ($response.StatusCode -ne "OK") {
        write-host "Error: " $response.StatusCode;
        return;
    }

    # get contents
    $stream = [System.IO.Stream]$response.GetResponseStream();
    $streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($stream);

    $data = $streamReader.ReadToEnd();

    $enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
    $filebytes = $enc.GetBytes($data) 

    $stream.Close();    
    $streamReader.Close();

    # save file        
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($Path, $filebytes)
}
catch [Exception]
{
    write-host "exception" $error[0]
}

$web.Dispose()
```

EDIT:
I was in good mood so I've completed also the code to download contents and save them to file system.

Comment: No. I don't mean this way. I am just trying to do the same operation as **Export** the aspx page from the SP designer.

Comment: The [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) way is quite cool: `@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString($url))" `

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is possible :

```
$web = get-spweb http://server/yoursite
$file = $web.GetFile("$($web.Url)/pages/home.aspx")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("$(gl)\$($file.Name)", $file.OpenBinary())
```

This will write in the current directory the content of the file "Pages/home.aspx"